# Multivariable chain rule and partial derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> The function $T(x,y)$ describes the temperature on every point on the plain. a person is moving on the unit circle $r(t)=i\cos t+j\sin t$, $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$ he feels the temperature $1-\sin t$.
>
> a.what is the warmest point on the track?
>
> b.prove that $P(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$) makes the realtion $T_x(P)-T_y(P)=1$

What I did for part $a$ was:

Since $T(x,y)$ describes the temperature on every point then the temperature that the person feels $(1-\sin t)$ can be $T(t)=1-sint$ , and since the maximum/minimum value of $\sin t$ can be $-1$ or $1$ then we will need the minimum value of it , and that point would be $\sin(\frac{2 \pi}{3})$ so we get $T(\frac{2 \pi}{3})=1-(-1)=2$ which means that $T(\frac{2 \pi}{3})=2$ is the warmest point.

And for part $b$:

so we have $r(t)=i\cos t+j\sin t$ which is $r(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$ according to the given information we get $\cos t=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and $\sin t=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ which means $t=\frac{\pi}{4}$

according to what I learned here I can use the chain rule, derivative along a curve( sorry if the translation is not right)
so I did $T'(t)=T_x(t,t)*-\sin t+T_y(t,t)*\cos(t)$ , $-\cos t=-T_x(t,t)*\sin t+T_y(t,t)*\cos t$ according to $\cos t=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and $\sin t=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ we can apply the numbers in the equation above and eventually we get $-1=-T_x(t,t)+T_y(t,t)$ lastly $T_x(p)-T_y(p)=1$

**my problem is I used this rule and actually all of this question without really knowing why I am using those rules , I just did it because the lecturer did something similar , Can anyone explain to me why I should do this? and if what I did is right?**

thank you for the help and tips!

Comment: The chain rule gives the derivative of the composition of two functions $g \circ f.$ If $f$ has derivative $f'(x)$ at the point $x$ and if $y = f(x)$ and the derivative of $g$ at $y$ is $g'(y)$ then the chain rule states that the derivative of the composition $g \circ f$ at $x$ is simply the composition of the corresponding derivatives $g'(y) \circ f'(x).$ When $g$ is a vector function and $f$ a curve, the composition $g \circ f$ corresponds "intuitively" to walking on the curve $g$ using the "path" determined by $f.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warmest point is when $\sin(t)=-1$, it happens when $t=\frac{3\pi}2$, that is the point $(0,-1)$.

---

Notice that

- $T$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.
- $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$.

Hence chain rule is a suitable tool for this type of problem.

$$T(t)=T(x(t), y(t))$$

$$T'(t) = \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} =\nabla T \cdot \left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)$$

Evaluating it at $t=\frac{\pi}4$,

$$-\cos \left( \frac{\pi}4\right)=  T_x(P)(-\sin \frac{\pi}4) + T_y(P)\cos \left(\frac{\pi}4 \right) $$

$$-1=  -T_x(P) + T_y(P) $$

$$T_x(P) - T_y(P)=1$$